# Bring in closest data point with respect to time from 2 dataframes panda

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have 2 dataframes, the first is dfweather(Datetimeindex is vdatetime):

```
vdatetime                  station  date         temp
2017-01-01 00:52:00+00:00   IAD 1/1/2017 0:52   45.00
2017-01-01 01:52:00+00:00   IAD 1/1/2017 1:52   45.00
2017-01-01 02:52:00+00:00   IAD 1/1/2017 2:52   45.00
2017-01-01 03:52:00+00:00   IAD 1/1/2017 3:52   44.10
2017-01-01 04:52:00+00:00   IAD 1/1/2017 4:52   42.10
```

The 2nd dataframe is dfload(Datetimeindex is vdatetime):

```
vdatetime                      date            load
2017-01-01 00:00:00+00:00   1/1/2017 0:00   483.52698
2017-01-01 00:05:00+00:00   1/1/2017 0:05   480.69008
2017-01-01 00:10:00+00:00   1/1/2017 0:10   480.28880
2017-01-01 00:15:00+00:00   1/1/2017 0:15   478.72021
2017-01-01 00:20:00+00:00   1/1/2017 0:20   476.37618
```

As above dfweather only has weather data at fixed points name hourly:52 mins but the load dataframe has load data every 5 minutes.  I'd like to bring in temp in dfweather to the closest time value in dfload (absolute value so either before or after), so for example if dfload time is 1/1/2017 at 0:20 and dfweather's closet value is 1/1/2017 0:02, then it brings in the weather at 0:02 at the dfload point at 0:20 on 1/1/2017.  I'm not sure how to complete this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `merge_asof`:

```
pd.merge_asof(dfload, dfweather, on='vdatetime', direction='nearest', suffixes=('load', 'weather'))

                  vdatetime      date_load       load station   date_weather  temp
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00+00:00  1/1/2017 0:00  483.52698     IAD  1/1/2017 0:52  45.0
1 2017-01-01 00:05:00+00:00  1/1/2017 0:05  480.69008     IAD  1/1/2017 0:52  45.0
2 2017-01-01 00:10:00+00:00  1/1/2017 0:10  480.28880     IAD  1/1/2017 0:52  45.0
3 2017-01-01 00:15:00+00:00  1/1/2017 0:15  478.72021     IAD  1/1/2017 0:52  45.0
4 2017-01-01 00:20:00+00:00  1/1/2017 0:20  476.37618     IAD  1/1/2017 0:52  45.0
```

Comment: this worked just needed to add in 'dfdemand.sort_values('vdatetime')' since it was throwing a left key unsorted error.